# Ajuda em alocar memória para um struct

Tags: c, c++

```
int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
cout << sizeof(Livro);
paragrafo();

int cont;
Livro *livros;


while(true){
    int op;
    cout << "1) Maior de 3 números";
    paragrafo();
    cout << "2) Preencher vetor de livros";
    paragrafo();
    cout << "3) Listar livros preenchidos";
    paragrafo();
    cout << "4) Gravar vetor de livros";
    paragrafo();
    cout << "5) Ler vetor de livros";
    paragrafo();
    cout << "0) Sair";
    paragrafo();
    cin >> op;

    switch (op){
        case 1:
            cout << "opção escolhida 1\n";
            maiorDe3();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "opção escolhida 2\n";
            if(cont == 0){
                cout << "caiu na primeira\n";
                livros = new Livro[cont + 3];
                registrarLivro(&cont, &livros[cont]);
            }
            else if(cont > 0){
                cout << "caiu na segunda\n";
                Livro *livrotemp;
                livrotemp = new Livro[cont + 10];
                registrarLivro(&cont, &livros[cont]);
                for(int i = 0; i < cont; i++){
                    livrotemp[i] = livros[i];
                }
                delete [] livros;
                livros = NULL;
                livros = new Livro[cont + 4];
                cout << " MEMORIA ALOCADA " << cont + 4 << " ";
                for(int i = 0; i < cont; i++){
                    livros[i] = livrotemp[i];
                }
                delete [] livrotemp;
                livrotemp = NULL;

            }
```

Gostaria de ajuda nessa parte do meu código, tentei fazer uma alocação de memória para um struct de modo que essa alocação é deletada e aumentada a cada livro novo adicionado no struct, porém não está funcionando a alocação de memória não aumenta de acordo com a variável cont, que é a quantidade de livros que estão registrados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ é uma linguagem diferente de C, em C++ :

1 - Você pode encapsular o cout << "..." e o paragrafo() em uma função só ( imaginando que paragrafo vai pular  para próx linha" )

```
template<typename T>
ostream& out( ostream& o, const T& t ) {
  return o << t << "\n"; 
}
```

2 - Se puder, evite essas estruturas "raw" de acessos de ponteiros, crie um vector

```
int main() {
   std::vector<Livro> livros;
   livro x;   // sem new, sem ponteiros
   livros.push_back(x); // aloca mais um espaço e copia o livro no vetor;    
   foo( livros[0] ); // chama função passando o livro "x"
}  // quando sai do escopo, livros vai ser apagado automaticamente sem delete[]
```

3 - O seu algoritmo de "vector grow" deveria estar em uma função separada do resto do código, uma implementação possível seria :

```
Livro* realocaVec(Livro* l, int tam_antigo, int tam_novo )  {
  Livro *result = new Livro[tam_novo];    // nada bom...
  std::copy_n( l, tam_antigo, result );   // include <algorithm> ok !
  delete [] l;                            // nada bom...
  return result;
}
```

Nesse exemplo acima, você pelo menos isolamos a copia do vetor da função "registrarLivro" que não tenho como saber o que ela está fazendo. Aparentemente, pelos parâmetros, vc deve estar inserindo informações no segundo parâmetro e aumentando o primeiro em 1 estou certo ? Isso não tem nada a ver com o crescimento do vetor.

4 - Agora o problema deve estar relacionado com o comando

```
livros = new Livro[cont + 4];
```

Suponha que cont = 10, nesse caso vc alocou um vetor de 14 posições e eu pergunto : em que variável está o numero 14 ? Nenhuma até agora.

No seu exemplo, você tem `cont` como variável com a quantidade de livros alocados, mas não está claro se ela é a mesma da quantidade de livros utilizados. Normalmente vc precisa de 2 variáveis uma `"size"` com o tamanho real do vetor alocado e uma `"cont"` com a quantidade de items já usados e quando vc for inserir mais um elemento no vetor e ocorrer `(cont == size)` vc chama realocaVec, fazendo o size ficar um pouco maior que o cont.

(só avisando que essa função já está muito bem desenvolvida dentro da classe std:vector)

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, o seu post foi perfeito eu não sabia dessas utilidades do C++ para trabalhar com o crescimento do vetor e você me deu novas ideias de como fazer isso, acho que da maneira que eu estava querendo era um pensamento mais voltado ultilizando C. Uma última dúvida, no seu item 4 ao utilizar o new para definir o espaço do cont + 4 na memória, vamos supor cont = 10, foi alocado um vetor de Livro com 14 posições na memória  certo? Eu não consigo desalocar essa memória e alocar denovo depois com um cont maior? Para ter mais posições.

Comment: Sim consegue desalocar, na função do item 3, vc passa 3 parâmetros : o vetor atual, tamanho do vetor atual e o tamanho novo a chamada fica assim : `livros = realocaVec(livros, cont, cont + 10 ) ; cont = cont + 10;` essa função já desaloca o anterior no comando `delete [] l`. Desse modo nem precisa do livrotemp e o corpo do`else if(cont > 0)` fica minusculo. Com exceção da linha cout << "memoria alocada" ...   O parágrafo todo se reduz apenas a essa chamada, desde o `Livro *livrotemp; ` até o `livrotemp = null`.